# Lists in HTML not displaying horizontally even after applying overflow and wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Copy the code and run the html file.
Put the JavaScript file in the scripts folder and css file in styles folder.

The problem is the `li` elements are not showing horizontally in a wrapped manner as it should.

When you run it and fill details and add student information, it shows it in the html page. Without refreshing fill another detail. Again, it shows.
The 2 `checkboxes` at the beginning tell the type of view and here is the problem. 
And I want it to be viewed horizontally. I don't want the elements to be displayed horizontally and once it crosses the `ul` element region, I want it to give a Horizontal scroll not a new line.

```js
var name;
var age;
var dob;
var id;
var street;
var city;
var id1;
//Variable declarations


function ver() {
  console.log("Vertical view");
  $("#displayDetails").removeClass("hor").addClass("ver");
}

function hor() {
  console.log("Horizontal View");
  $("#displayDetails").removeClass("ver").addClass("hor");
}

$(window).load(function() {
  // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
  console.log("window is loaded");
});




$(document).ready(function() {
  // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
  console.log("Inside document.ready(function())");

  $("button").click(function() {

    console.log("name fetched");
    name = $("#name").val();
    age = $("#age").val();
    dob = $("#dob").val();

    street = $("#street").val();
    city = $("#city").val();



    // alert(city + "id " +id + "stret " + street);



    console.log(age);
    //Validation Results
    var status;
    status = new Validate();

    var nameStat = true;
    if (!status.validateName(name)) {

      console.log("Name incorrect");

    } else if (!status.validateAge(age)) {

      console.log("age incorrect");
    } else {

      var a = new Student(name, age, dob, street, city);
    }





    $('input').val("");



  });
});



//Validation Methods
var Validate = function() {

  this.validateName = function(name) {
    //alert(name);
    if (name == "") {
      console.log("Name cannot be blank");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }

    /*else if(name == /[a-z]/)
          {
    
           console.log("Good name");     
           return true;
          }*/


  }


  this.validateAge = function(age) {

    console.log("validating age");

    if (age == "") {
      console.log("Age cannot be blank");
      $("#age").focus();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }

    /*else if(age==/[0-9]/)
         {
          console.log("Please enter a Valid age!");
         }
            else{return true;}*/

  }

}
this.validateCity = function(city) {
  if (city == "") {
    alert("City name cannot be blank");
    $("#city").focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}
this.validateStreet = function(street) {
  if (street == "") {
    alert("Street cannot be blank");
    $("#street").focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log("Got Street");
    return true;
  }

}

this.validateDob = function(dob) {
  if (dob == "") {
    alert("DOB cannot be blank");
    $("#dob").focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}



var count = 0;
var Student = function(name, age, dob, addressId) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.dob = dob;
  this.addressId = addressId;


  //alert("Street : " + addressId.street);


  ++count;
  $("#displayDetails").append("<li id=count><input type='checkbox' onclick='delete1()'>" + " <div>" +

    "Name: " + name +
    "<br/>Age: " + age +
    "<br/>Date of Birth: " + dob +
    "<br/>Street: " + street +
    "<br/>City: " + city

    + "</div>" + "</li>");

}

function delete1() {

  $("#count").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/hor.css">
</head>
<body>

  <b>Select View</b>
  Vertical

  <input value="vertical" type="radio" name="view" onclick="ver()" />Horizontal
  <input value="horizontal" type="radio" name="view" onclick="hor()" />


  <h2><i>Students Information Form</i></h2>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" id="name" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Age" id="age" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="dob" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="street" placeholder="street" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="city" />
  <br/>

  <button>Register</button>
  <br/>
  <div style="background-color:#999999;" id="box">
    <ul id="displayDetails" class="hor ver"></ul>

  </div>
  <script src="scripts/script2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle for this. Its mush easier to help

Comment: Its impossible to help you. No demo no help, and you cannot ask here to people for creating files and try, make a demo.

Comment: separate your CSS, HTML and JS, make a snippet and a fiddle, also: display: inline-block;

Comment: I cannot spot any `<li>` in your html.

Comment: provide css. there is no css in your code..

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal appearance,
do this in CSS,

```
ul#displayDetails{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: #999999;
  max-width: 300px;
}

ul#displayDetails li{
  padding-right:40px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

Also remove the `background-color:#999999;` from the parent `div` of `ul`